# Cannot read property "length" of undefined?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to make something for a little community I'm in. But I'm not very well versed in JavaScript and NodeJS yet. The script I'm making, is supposed to first find all possible combinations of a list of users in groups of 6.

Then I need to take each of those groups skill rating average, and compare so that I can find the two that matches the closest. This way we get two teams that can play against each other, and be somewhat balanced at least.

But my first issue is that I seem to be unable to even print out anything from the array that I'm making, and I don't understand why.

```
var filePath = 'data.txt';

function readFile() {
    var data = [];
    var lineReader = require('readline').createInterface({
        input: require('fs').createReadStream(filePath)
    });
    lineReader.on('line', function(line) {
        var splitString = line.split(',');
        var arr = { 
            sr: splitString[0],
            role: splitString[1],
            discord: splitString[3]
        };
        data.push(arr);
        console.log(arr);
    });

    lineReader.on('close', () => {
        return data;
    });
}

function balance() {
    var data = readFile();
    for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        console.log(data[i]);
    }
}

balance();
```

The output is always undefined. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Reading is asynchronous and you need to wait the read process to finish before printing out the data. The task is simply not finished and that's why you see nothing ...

Comment: @codtex Well, can I force it to be synchronized instead of asynchronous?

Comment: I'l try to refactor your code to work. But this is the most common issue ever, when comming to node.js!

Comment: @AlexandruOlaru It's quite annoying it's done this way in Node. I get why they do it on a website, but in Node? Eh. I'd have liked some more synchronous calls.

Comment: Mha, @codtex already responded... :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is not to change the nature of the reading function, instead change your approach.

I will give you two options.

**Using callback:**

```
var filePath = 'data.txt';

function readFile(callback) {
    var data = [];
    var lineReader = require('readline').createInterface({
        input: require('fs').createReadStream(filePath)
    });
    lineReader.on('line', function (line) {
        var splitString = line.split(',');
        var arr = {
            sr: splitString[0],
            role: splitString[1],
            discord: splitString[3]
        };
        data.push(arr);
        console.log(arr);
    });
    lineReader.on('close', () => {
        callback(data);
    });
}

function balance() {
    readFile(function (data) {
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            console.log(data[i]);
        }
    });
}

balance();
```

**Using Promise:**

```
var filePath = 'data.txt';

function readFile() {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        var data = [];
        var lineReader = require('readline').createInterface({
            input: require('fs').createReadStream(filePath)
        });
        lineReader.on('line', function (line) {
            var splitString = line.split(',');
            var arr = {
                sr: splitString[0],
                role: splitString[1],
                discord: splitString[3]
            };
            data.push(arr);
            console.log(arr);
        });
        lineReader.on('close', () => {
            resolve(data);
        });
    });
}

function balance() {
    readFile().then(function (data) {
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            console.log(data[i]);
        }
    }, function (error) {

    });
}

balance();
```

Comment: I went with the callback solution, but it would be nice to see the await approach too @AlexandruOlaru

Answer (score 1):

**Using async await**

```
const filePath = './data.txt';

async function readFile() {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    const data = [];
    const lineReader = require('readline').createInterface({
      input: require('fs').createReadStream(filePath),
    });

    lineReader.on('line', (line) => {
      const [sr, role, discord] = line.split(',');
      const arr = {
        sr,
        role,
        discord,
      };
      data.push(arr);
    });

    lineReader.on('close', () => {
      resolve(data);
    });
  });
}

async function balance() {
  const data = await readFile();
  for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i += 1) {
    console.log(data[i]);
  }

  return 1;
}

balance().then(() => { });
```

**Using observer pattern**

```
const { EventEmitter } = require('events');
const fs = require('fs');

class FileParser extends EventEmitter {
  constructor(file) {
    super();
    this.file = file;
  }

  parse() {
    const self = this;
    const data = [];
    const lineReader = require('readline').createInterface({
      input: require('fs').createReadStream(self.file),
    });

    lineReader.on('line', (line) => {
      const [sr, role, discord] = line.split(',');
      const arr = {
        sr,
        role,
        discord,
      };
      data.push(arr);
    });

    lineReader.on('close', () => {
      self.emit('done', data);
    });

    return this;
  }
}

const fileParser = new FileParser('./data.txt');
fileParser
  .parse()
  .on('done', (data) => {
    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i += 1) {
      console.log(data[i]);
    }
  });
```

Refactored a bit to use the latest ES6 syntax;

Comment: I will post one more method with asynchronous dealing in node.js so it will be 4 different methods :D